# D3.js in line Chart fetch data from local variable

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3.js so please help I am trying to implement a line chart but i want to fetch the data from local variable

but getting error at this line

```
var cities = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id))
```

when i `console.log(data.columns);`  i am getting undefined

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
```

but getting this error

[here](http://codepen.io/7deepakpatil/pen/LRkEoO?editors=1000) is the code pen

I want to implement something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPlBq.png)

Comment: Is `data.columns` is an array ? print `data.columns` in console.

Comment: @AatifBandey    i get it as undefined pls click the here button in the above description

Comment: i dont find this `data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id))` this code in your codepen

Comment: @AatifBandey ...sorry i just deleted the line by mistakenly ...can u have a look now...line numbet is 2246

Comment: There is no key named `columns` inside `data` it should be `data.map(function(id){})`

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use the `d3.v4.min.js` by `<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>`.

I came up with the same Error, and fixed it by changing `<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/assets/js/d3.js"></script>` to `<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>`. I guess that something has changed between these two versions of `d3.js`.

Answer (score 0):

As per [codepen](http://codepen.io/7deepakpatil/pen/LRkEoO?editors=1000) there is no key named `columns` inside data
Try this

```
var cities = data.map(function(id, index){     
  return {
    id: id,
    values : {
      date : id.date,
      temperature:id[index]
    }
  }
});`
```